# How to prevent ListView scrolling while touching/swiping/fling its row?

Tags: android, listview, gesture

I need to stop ListView to respond on user gestures if those gestures are made in some particular ListView's row - How to do that? Target ListView's row view has onTouchListener set and I cant recognize swipe/flip because of ListView up/down scroll. So if I move finger a bit up or down - ListView intercepts that and scrolls in corresponding direction. So I need somehow to rule it like if Y-coord chaged more than some amount - let ListView to scroll and if not - recognize a gesture as fling/swipe. OnTouchListener is

```
private int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 1;
private int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 300;

final OnTouchListener flingSwipeListener =  new OnTouchListener() {
    float touchX;
    float touchY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {                   
        if (Math.abs(touchY - event.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
            // right to left swipe
            else if (touchX - event.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                    Log.i("flingSwipe","right to left swipe");
            } 
            // left to right swipe
            else if (event.getX() - touchX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                    Log.i("flingSwipe","left to right swipe");
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
};
```

This onTouchListner was set to one particular row. I need to freeze ListView while onTouchListener recognizes the gesture but if it fails I need to send the MotionEvent to the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to disable touch listener on particular row .  than this is simple .

set a tag on desired list row . in getview list adapter class.

e.g :

```
ABCList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent,
                    false);

            if(position == YOUR_DESIRED_ROW)
                          row.setTag("disableThisRow")

            return row;
        }


    }
```

then edit touch listener like this.

```
 final OnTouchListener flingSwipeListener =  new OnTouchListener() {
    float touchX;
    float touchY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
       String isRow=view.getTag();
       if(isRow.equals("disableThisRow"))return false;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {                   
        if (Math.abs(touchY - event.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
            // right to left swipe
            else if (touchX - event.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                    Log.i("flingSwipe","right to left swipe");
            } 
            // left to right swipe
            else if (event.getX() - touchX > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE){
                    Log.i("flingSwipe","left to right swipe");
            }
        }

        return true;

    }
};
```

this will disable touch for disired list item.. hope this helps.
or if you more gesture listeners than that will be also similar to this.
hope it helps

Comment: no, I need to disable ListView's built-in touch detector/recognizer if I swiping its particular row. Because I need to freeze ListView while swiping its row.

Comment: ok what you had to do is whenever user touches  on your desired row. than disable list scrolling. isn't it?.   and when user touches on other row , enable default scrolling.

Comment: yes, just like I added below the code in my question. I need to freeze ListView while user makes gestures in particular ListView's row. All other ListView's rows must act as usual. Moreover I need to transfer gesture to the ListView when I detect there was too big move by Y axis in my OnTouchListener to make user able to scroll ListView even thru my special row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable vertical scrolling of ListView when any horizontal scrolling (swipe) is detected then use the following solution - override onTouchEvent in your custom ListView class and replace action MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE to MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

```
public class ListView2 extends ListView
{
    private enum ScrollDirection
    {
        Horizontal,
        Vertical
    }

    private final int touchSlop;

    private float downX = 0;
    private float downY = 0;

    private ScrollDirection scrollDirection;

    public ListView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        switch (ev.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (scrollDirection == null)
                {
                    if (Math.abs(downX - ev.getX()) > touchSlop) scrollDirection = ScrollDirection.Horizontal;
                    else if (Math.abs(downY - ev.getY()) > touchSlop) scrollDirection = ScrollDirection.Vertical;
                }
                if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.Horizontal) ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                scrollDirection = null;
                downX = ev.getX();
                downY = ev.getY();
                break;

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Of course you can make checking logic whether to disable vertical scrolling more complex.